# Reset mysql colum values to default after specific using Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am new to web development I am making some web services using java servlets, and I am stuck in so many How to do it? stuff :(

I am developing an application in which I need to reset the mysql table column values back to default values at some time let's say we need to reset the counter @ every Sunday 10:00 pm.

is there any thing like alarm manager in Java or mysql that can run all the time in background and trigger @ specific time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might also use the event scheduling mechanism of [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

this depends on the version of mysql and whether it is enabled or not

Answer (score 2):

Java has a good interface ScheduledExecutorService.
You can try this code

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
//every day to execute
long everyDayDelay = 24*60*60*1000;
//first time to execute, it can be your special date
//for example 5 seconds after launch
long timeToExecute = System.currentTimeMillis()+5*1000;

service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task(), getTimeToLaunch(timeToExecute), everyDayDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where

```
//return difference between now and timeToExecute
public static long getTimeToLaunch(long timeToExecute){
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return timeToExecute - current;
}

class Task implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run task!");
    }    
}
```

UPDATE: Class to execute your sql-tasks

```
public class SqlExecutionService1 {

    public static final long everyDayDelay = 24*60*60*1000;

    public SqlExecutionService1(){
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        //every day to execute

        //first time to execute
        //for example 5 seconds after launch
        long timeToExecute = System.currentTimeMillis()+5*1000;

        service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new SqlTask1(), getTimeToLaunch(timeToExecute), everyDayDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private long getTimeToLaunch(long timeToExecute){
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return timeToExecute - current;
    }
}
class SqlTask1 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your sql tasks
    }    
}
```

To create this class, when your app server starts - use method init() in one of your main servlets.
Example -

```
public class MainInitServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() {
       new SqlExecutionService1();    
    }
}
```

Comment: where I can put first snippet, I don't think we can put in the Servlet from where I can initiate the the scheduler task, such that It can be independent of the pc and relies on server only.

Comment: @NixitPatel may be you can create a specific class, where scheduler will be created. I think you can create this class, when you app server starts.

Comment: can you tell me which class is that, I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 2):

The Data of a Database should be the basis **for** calculation, not the result of calculations. In example Bills wont ever be successfully revised.

I guess this fact will ever be a clash between Programmers and Architects.

Comment: Hey think, if a online-game like Travian has a bug in over-time-calculation of gold, if you fix that bug, the gamer's gold will be calculated correctly. But if you update the result in the database you must hardly manual recalulate all his over-time-calulation of gold.

Comment: I am making an app in which user suppose to have a daily top 20, items or weekly to 20 item, can you guys point a better way to do that.

Comment: @NixitPatel What is a problem to create always a new top? Then you can get fresh top by current date.

Comment: @NixitPatel Now, I think bad) As said Peter, you should use database for calculation. For example - you have items and their sales. Every sale have date. I think by using only dates of sales you can count weekly top of items. You will only need a good sql query=)

Comment: @NixitPatel you have the good argumentation of a programmers. So the architects counter: Ok, thats what views are for.

Answer (score 1):

`is there any thing like alarm manager in Java or mysql that can run all the time in background and trigger @ specific time.`

look at a API called [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) , where your program can schedule Jobs and it will run it at that time.

use method `execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecution)` use to fire trigger.

EG:

```
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
// Retrieve scheduler 
Scheduler scheduler = null;
try {
scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
}
catch (SchedulerException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

//this is a job
JobDetail job = new JobDetail("jobDetail", "jobDetailGroup",       ImplementedJob.class);
 SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("Trigger Name","defaultGroup", DATE);

// schedule 
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
// start the scheduler
scheduler.start();
```